# Secure JSON file to be readed without permision

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, server

I have PHP script which writes some JSON data into mySecretData.json file. This script runs periodically every 10 minutes via CRON. I'm accessing this JSON file via AJAX from both my website and Windows 10 app. In future I plan maybe to sell the content of my secret file. How can I protect this file to be readed without my permission?

At this moment anybody can explore my website's source code to get the URL from which the website reads the secret data. Trying to sell this content would be pretty useless. My JSON file contain only few lines of data, so I don't want to use database.

How can I secure my file(s)? Thank you very much!

Comment: Place the file **outside** the webroot. Read it with php if some condition is met

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment

```
file structure
/
/secret
    /secret.json
/public_html //<--webroot
    /getJson.php


//getJson.php
//complicated auth logic goes here
if(isset($_GET['authtoken'] && $_GET['authtoken']=='im_ok_guv_honest'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    readfile('../secret/secret.json');
    die();
}
die('not authorized');
```

Comment: But this way anyone could view this PHP script and read my credentials or simply call this PHP script to retrieve my secret data. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Nobody can view the php source, thats on the server. They would have to call the script with the correct credentials (in this case `getJson.php?authtoken=im_ok_guv_honest`). Obviously your actual auth logic would be more complicated, but thats beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: But if someone will read my website's JS script file with AJAX request which will bet targeting to /getJson.php then he know where the getJson.php file is and he could download it and read it as anything else on the internet. Excuse my dullness - I'm server-side a PHP newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You should move it away from your web folder and having a script streaming it after checking some credentials for a database for example.

You could add some IP verification to prevent same credentials from being used by several persons